# Histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to plot a histogram. I also want to have a density instead of frequency in y axis.

I am able to create the histogram but the y-axis is not changing to density.

[image]

Can you please help me?

Best Regards,
Dipen Bista

```
test=data.frame(c(0.17,0.39,0.24,0.24,0.17,0.42,0.33,0.25,0.36,0.26,0.24,0.16))
names(test) = 'ratio'
ggplot(data=test,aes(x=test$ratio,y=..density..)) + 
 geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0.1,0.5, by=0.1),
          col="black",
          fill="light gray",
          alpha=.8)+
          labs(title="Histogram of Length ratio")+
          labs(x='Angle',y='Density')+
          theme_bw()
```

Comment: Just giving it the name "Density" does not change the Y-axis to a density measure.

Comment: Perhaps _read_ `?geom_histogram`, keeping a keen  out for "Computed variables"

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
test = data.frame(c(0.17,0.39,0.24,0.24,0.17,0.42,0.33,0.25,0.36,0.26,0.24,0.16))
ggplot(test, aes(x = test$ratio)) + 
  geom_density()
```